# Sinch JavaScript to PSTN call voice missing of one second

Tags: javascript, sinch

I am using Sinch JavaScript API/SDK and I am using it to call PSTN numbers, now when the receiver receives the phone and says something, the voice for the first one second is lost somewhere, and that is really important for us as the receiver mostly says their name in that second and then we have no idea whom we are speaking to, and in professional calls that is really hitting us.

I tried logging the call.incomingStreamURL and it is undefined untill the notification of unmuting the call.

Regards

Comment: Do you have a url where I can look at it and try it out?

Comment: I'll definitely try to arrange one for you

Comment: As there are holidays in our country until Thursday, I won't be able to produce a link until that, but we are using the default sinch PSTN calling example

Comment: @cjensen please the URL 'https://sinchpstnsample.azurewebsites.net/index.html' can be used for a sample.

Also please note on the console that we get an error 
    `sinch.min.js:4 Warning, no proxy configured (1). Will try to add candidate without srflx reference RTCPeerConnection {localDescription: RTCSessionDescription, remoteDescription: RTCSessionDescription, signalingState: "stable", iceGatheringState: "complete", iceConnectionState: "completed"}`

Comment: Hi,I cant reprocue taht error, the warning is ok, it  should be an info not a warning.